# Xamarin android: Consuming Java library from C#

Tags: c#, android, binding, xamarin.android

I have built a binding library in Mono for Android to utilize a JAR file that uses JNI as well. I have tested the JAR file as an executable in eclipse and it runs fine. I then build it as a library, and export it to my binding library, rebuild the binding library. When I run the C# code and try to instantiate an object in the JAVA code, it throws an exception:

> Exception of type "No Class Definition Found Error" was thrown.

The class is known at compile time but apparently not at run time, i.e. the binding library created does not know the class.

Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: Does the jar have a `.so` file included with it?